# CentOS service shows up twice in process list

Tags: linux, systemctl

I need to sync a directory between two servers and decided to create a service which listens to changes in a file and runs rsync.

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/mediasync.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=SyncCdnImages

[Service]
#Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mediasync.sh
#Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/usr/bin/mediasync.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
inotifywait -mr -e close_write -e create "/var/www/html/folder/backend/utils/sync.log" | while read line

do
        rsync -avzr --update /var/www/html/cdnimages/* myip:/var/www/html/cdnimages/cdnimages/
done
```

`ps aux | grep sync`

```
root     25540  0.0  0.0 115244  1424 ?        Ss   11:31   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mediasync.sh
root     25541  0.0  0.0   6472   408 ?        S    11:31   0:00 inotifywait -mr -e close_write -e create /var/www/html/folder/backend/utils/sync.log
root     25542  0.0  0.0 115244   392 ?        S    11:31   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mediasync.sh
```

I start the service using `systemctl start mediasync` but what I don't understand is why it appears twice in the process list. Is this normal behavior?

Edit:

Killing one of the services for ex `kill 25540`, kills the other two as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` in your bash script is executed as a forked child process of the original bash.

This is normal behaviour.

If you do `ps auxf` you'll see the parent/child relationship, although it wont say `while` as the command name as `while` is a bash internal command.